# why this code works in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

char array[2];
array[0] = 'q';
array[1] = 'a';
printf("%s",array);

return 0;
}
```

if you ask me this code should not work. printf prints array[2] like string but it's not a string. When i execute it, it works perfectly. Can you explain why?

Comment: Hmm... How do you think "string" are represented in C?

Comment: It doesn't work. Code "works" if it does what you expect. This code does not do what you expect. It has a bug and therefore doesn't work. Fix the bug and the mystery will go away. Yes, buggy code will do strange things that you don't expect and have trouble understanding. That's a good reason not to write buggy code. (Buggy code is *much* harder to understand than good code. Until you fairly thoroughly understand valid code, I wouldn't suggest even trying to understand buggy code.)

Comment: You really shold invest in a beginner's book on C. Without understanding the fundamentals there's going to be a lot of things that don't make sense ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When i execute it, it works perfectly.

You just got (un)lucky: your code exhibits *undefined behavior*, because it lets the `printf`'s `%s` parameter run off the end of the sequence of characters that is not null-terminated.

A string in C is a sequence of `char`, which must have an extra character with the value `0`, called the null terminator. Here is a way to make your code work without undefined behavior:

```
char array[3];
array[0] = 'q';
array[1] = 'a';
array[2] = '\0';
```

Comment: Actually, he got unlucky. The code didn't do what he expected it to and hid a defect.

Answer (score 3):

In C, `String` is identical to character arrays. There is no such thing as `String` in C.

Comment: It might be worth noting that what he has is actually undefined behavior because there's no terminating `\0`

Comment: when i say string i mean array of characters with terminating '\0'. this way printf doesn't know where to stop, so why it shows no errors?

Comment: @overflowed: Something had to occupy the byte after the end of the array, and it just happened to be a zero. Because the code is buggy, it depends on what happens to be in memory after the end of the array.