# Typecasting a pointer and assigning it more memory than malloc'd doesnt throw any error

Tags: c, casting, malloc

I am learning C and was trying to understand typecasting and memory allocation.

I wrote a small code and thought it to fail.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct A {
    int x;
    int y;
};    
int main()
{
    int *i;
    float *f;
    struct A *ptr;
    i = (int *)malloc(4);
    if(i==NULL) {
        printf("\n failed to allocate memory \n");
        return 1;
    }
    *i=10;
    printf(" %d \n",*i);
    f = (float *)i;
    *f = 10.2;
    printf(" %f \n",*f);
    ptr = (struct A *)f;
    ptr->x=10;
    ptr->y=20;
    printf(" %hd \n",ptr->x);
    printf(" %hd \n",ptr->y);
}
```

I expected this code to fail because I allocated just 4 bytes of memory and type casted the same pointer to point to float ( 4 bytes) and to  the structure which has 8 bytes. I though it to give seg-fault but rather it prints out the values w/o any issue.

Is there anything I am missing.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897817/why-this-code-works-in-c

Comment: "I expected this code to fail" - don't be afraid, it **did fail,** just not in a visible way.

Comment: Sigh. All compilers need a “-EnableRunTimeTestsForUndefinedBehavior” switch that is on by default until you find a code to turn it off, and the code shall be banned from search engines and published only in programming language textbooks. Or maybe only available as a cryptographic signature issued by various authorizing agencies after you pass a programming test.

Comment: Although this is somewhat related to [SO 13897817](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897817/), it is not a very direct duplicate.  In particular, the other question is not dealing with `malloc()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably still writing into some memory area allocated for the the data segment of your program, so segmentation fault does not occur. It is difficult to say which data are you overwriting and that impact this will have later. As the program is very short, under some specific circumstances may not have any impact at all. The larger program most probably would crash after running for some time ("delayed crash").

This is C, the *middle level* language. If you need this safety, use the high level language instead, there is no lack of these.

Answer (score 2):

This is called *undefined behavior*. You're making `ptr` point to the same location as the `float` in memory, so you're overwriting it along with the `int` and you're taking up the 4 bytes after the allocated memory. It didn't fail because you were lucky.

Comment: From a debugger's perspective, I have to agree :D